# 3-D graph using the library LDAvis and function createJSON

Tags: r

I am looking for the way to make a 3-D plot from the outcome of my Latent Dirichlet Allocation function. Here is my code:

```
library(lda)
example <- c("price house expectations growth positive 
         scotland report increase demand rise", "price house luxury beautiful mansion
         scotland report increase demand rise", "price house maximum growth expected 
          scotland report increase demand rise")

# converting the data into lda format 
corpus <- lexicalize(example, lower=TRUE)
corpus$documents

K=2
num.iterations=100
alpha=0.5
eta=0.5

result = lda.collapsed.gibbs.sampler(corpus$documents, K, corpus$vocab, num.iterations, 
                                     alpha,eta, initial = NULL, burnin = NULL, 
                                     compute.log.likelihood = FALSE,trace = 0L, 
                                     freeze.topics = FALSE)
```

Could someone help me provide me help to make the graph. So far this is what I have tried:

```
library(LDAvis)
createJSON(as.matrix(corpus$phi), integer(corpus$term.frequency), 
           as.character(corpus$vocab), topic.proportion)
```

Nevertheless, I know I am making a mistake but I do not know where. I get the following answer:

```
Error in array(x, c(length(x), 1L), if (!is.null(names(x))) list(names(x),  : 
  'data' must be of a vector type, was 'NULL'
```

Kind regards,